# How can ActiveAdmin start sorting columns after the first click on columns' header in ascending order?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

By default **ActiveAdmin** seems to sort all the columns in index pages (after the user click on header's column) in descending order.

Is it possible to specify the initial direction of sorting for all columns?

Note: I'm not referring to the `config.sort_order` which only creates the default order for when a user arrives to the index page.

Comment: Please elaborate " initial direction of sorting for all columns"

Comment: When you sort you can have two "directions": ascending and descending. The initial one, in the ActiveAdmin case for all columns, is the "descending" one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately what you want to do doesn't seem configurable because [`desc`, the default sort, is hard-coded](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/lib/active_admin/views/components/table_for.rb#L147). However, if you would like a monkey patch, you can put code below in `config/initializers/active_admin.rb` which overrides the default behaviour.

```
module ActiveAdmin
  module Views
    class TableFor < Arbre::HTML::Table    
      def order_for_sort_key(sort_key)
        current_key, current_order = current_sort
        return 'asc' unless current_key == sort_key
        current_order == 'desc' ? 'asc' : 'desc'
      end
    end
  end
end
```